# C# array of const string

Tags: c#

I have a set of C# constants, for example:

```
LoanApplication.CONST_FIELD_NAME_DOB
LoanApplication.CONST_FIELD_NAME_EMPLOYMENTSTATUS
```

at a later time, I want to create an array that holds these constants.

I have tried:

```
const string [] Constants = 
{
    LoanApplication.CONST_FIELD_NAME_DOB,
    LoanApplication.CONST_FIELD_NAME_EMPLOYMENTSTATUS,
}
```

but I get the error:

> a const field of a reference type can only be initialized with null

There are lots of questions that relate to this problem, but none where the array contains a list of existing constants.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also [Why does C# limit the set of types that can be declared as const?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441420/447156)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an array is a reference type, it can only be set to a default of something that doesn't need the code to run, so `null` is the only option to assign the `const` to.

Instead of `const`, you could use `static readonly` here, which isn't entirely the same (it is evaluated at runtime instead of compile time), but will come the closest to what you want.