# Why does C# have 'readonly' and 'const'?

Tags: c#, .net

I come from a C++ background and am trying to become proficient in C#. It seems like C# always has 2 types of modifiers wherever C++ had one. For example, in C++ there is `&` for references and then in C# there is `ref` and `out` and I have to learn the subtle differences between them. Same with `readonly` and `const`, which are the topic of this thread. Can someone explain to me what the subtle differences are between the 2? Maybe show me a situation where I accidentally use the wrong one and my code breaks.

Comment: would you mind search in google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly

Comment: Or try searching here. Closing for duplicate.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary My question is more about why their exist 2 such modifiers in the first place. My enthusiasm for learning C# is going to drop unless I'm convinced that the language features are necessary.

Comment: I suspect you'll get more mileage from learning C++.  Find out why `const_cast<>` is provided by the language.  And why it had to add the `mutable` keyword later.  All hacks around the not-so-great *const* keyword, hacks that the C# designers were well aware of.

Comment: You probably should stop learning C# then... There are a lot of things that are not strictly necessary - like `?:` and `??` when simple `if` is enough, multiple ways to represent delegates,.. Note that while asking for "why feature X is designed in language in particular way" are on-topic such post should show reasonable understanding/research about feature to stay on its own. In current state of the question it clear duplicate due to just asking about differences.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441420/why-does-c-sharp-limit-the-set-of-types-that-can-be-declared-as-const

Answer (score 0):

Readonly: Can only be set in the constructor.

Const: Is a COMPILE TIME CONSTANT. I.e. can not be determined at runtime.